# find median in R

Tags: r, median

```
socialsec  
411223  
420211   
420604
430404 
431030
440127
910415
950110
740505
910101
```

This is a number column of Swedish social security number, in the format yymmdd I want to find the median year for them. (
If the person then is above the median age, i would like to create i new column were this person is "old". I would like to call the new column "age"
The same for those who are younger than the median age. In the same column "age", they stand as "young"
This is certainly a very basic question, But I am not an experienced user of R.

Answer (score 3):

If your initial data.frame is `df`:

```
df$socialsec = as.Date(paste0('19',as.character(df$socialsec)), format='%Y%m%d')
df$age = ifelse(df$socialsec < median(df$socialsec), 'old', 'young')
```

Where:

```
df = structure(list(socialsec = c(411223L, 420211L, 420604L, 430404L, 
431030L, 440127L, 910415L, 950110L, 740505L, 910101L)), .Names = "socialsec",     
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: The way I understand it, I'm guessing the first 2 numbers are year of birth so probably, people born in 1941 are older than people born in 1995... (same remark for @akrun's solution)

Comment: Exactly, some tipo in the code. I also formated the date to make it clear!

Comment: It looks (way) better (and logic) like that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do ('df' from @Colonel Beauvel's post)

```
df$age <- with(df, c('young', 'old')[(socialsec > median(socialsec))+1L])
```